# How can I access the local storage on page reload in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

I need help solving this problem where I am creating an Account component and store the token in the local storage after logging in. When I navigate to Account page the first time, I was able to access the state from redux store. If I refresh the page, the value is null but the token still in local storage. How can I use the token to do a fetch call while loading the page? I already have the method calls inside of useEffect() method. Why does it set all the values to null for user and profile fields? Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you so much.

```js
// Account.js 

import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import profilePic from '../../../img/profile.jpeg';
import {
    AccountContainer,
    IconStyle,
    H1Container,
    SectionContainer,
    ProfileContainer,
    FormContainer,
    InputContainer,
    InputText,
    DivContainer,
    LabelContainer,
    EditButton,
    PasswordButton,
    ImageContainer,
    ImageStyle,
    ButtonStyle
} from './Account.style';

import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Spinner from '../../spinner/Spinner';
import store from '../../../redux/store';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadUser } from '../../../redux/actions/authAction';
import { getUserProfile } from '../../../redux/actions/profileAction';


const Account = ({ loadUser, auth: { user }, getUserProfile, profile: { profile, loading } }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        // load user
        loadUser();
        // get current profile 
        getUserProfile();
    }, [loadUser, getUserProfile]);

    return (
        profile && loading === null
            ?
            <Spinner />
            :
            <Fragment>
                <AccountContainer>
                    <H1Container className="text-center">
                        <p>
                            <IconStyle className="fa fa-user-circle" />
                        </p>
                        <h1>My Account</h1>
                        <p>Update your email or change your password here</p>
                    </H1Container>
                </AccountContainer>

                <SectionContainer>
                    <ProfileContainer>
                        <ImageContainer>
                            <p>
                                <ImageStyle src={profilePic} alt="Profile picture" />
                            </p>
                            <ButtonStyle type="button">Change Photo</ButtonStyle>
                        </ImageContainer>

                    </ProfileContainer>
                    <FormContainer>
                        <form>
                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="submit"></LabelContainer>
                                <EditButton type="button">Edit Profile</EditButton>
                                <PasswordButton type="button">Change Password</PasswordButton>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="username">Username</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value={user.username} />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="fullname">Full Name</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value={user.fullname} />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="email">Email</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="email" className="form-control" readOnly value='email' />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="country">Country</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value='country' />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="blogs">Number of blog posts</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value="20" />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="facebook">Facebook</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value="www.facebook.com" />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="twitter">Twitter</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value="www.twitter.com" />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="linkedin">Linkedin</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value="www.linkedin.com" />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="instagram">Instagram</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value="www.instagram.com" />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                            <DivContainer>
                                <LabelContainer htmlFor="join">Join Date</LabelContainer>
                                <InputContainer>
                                    <InputText type="text" className="form-control" readOnly value="09-10-2020 3:00PM" />
                                </InputContainer>
                            </DivContainer>

                        </form>
                    </FormContainer>
                </SectionContainer>
            </Fragment>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    profile: state.profile
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadUser, getUserProfile })(Account);
```

Comment: You can try [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for these situations if you don't want to have to manage it yourself

Comment: can you share the loadUser and getUserProfile actions ?

Comment: @SethLutske since I'm already using local storage, I would want to understand how to implement it in the application.

Comment: @DaimellahSofiane sure I can share the action and reducer.


// action
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
    // check if token exists 
    if (localStorage.token) {
        // call function to set it to the global header 
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_FAIL
        })
    }
}

Comment: // reducer
const initialState = {
    // get token from local storage 
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOADED: 
            return{
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true, 
                loading: false, 
                user: action.payload
            }
    default: 
        return state;
  }
}

export default authReducer;

Comment: Would you mind actually putting the `loadUser` and `getUserProfile` in the original question in code blocks?  Its very hard to read in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

@SethLutske
Yes, I think so.
Please see the action and reducer and let me know if this helps.

```js
// LOAD USER WITH AUTH TOKEN
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
    // check if token exists 
    if (localStorage.token) {
        // call function to set it to the global header 
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_FAIL
        })
    }
}
```

```js
// define initial states
const initialState = {
    // get token from local storage 
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOADED: 
            return{
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true, 
                loading: false, 
                user: action.payload
            }
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS: 
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            // set token 
            localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
            return{
                ...state,
                ...action.payload, 
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading: false
            } 
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case AUTH_FAIL:
        case CLEAR_PROFILE:
        case LOGOUT:  
            // remove token 
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return{
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                loading: false,
                user: null
            }    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default authReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setState the token form localStorage in componentDidMount of Account component.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        token:localStorage.getItem('token')
    })
}
```